# How to get all form input values using blur event in `addEventListener`?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get form values dynamically using `addEventListener` but I am just getting first input, not getting other inputs.

This is my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    const user_input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]');

    user_input.addEventListener(
      'blur',
      function(event) {
        var target = event.target;

        if (target.name == "first_name") {
          console.log('first name : ' + target.value);
        }

        if (target.name == "mid_name") {
          console.log('mid name : ' + target.value);
        }

        if (target.name == "last_name") {
          console.log('last name : ' + target.value);
        }

        if (target.name == "password") {
          console.log('password : ' + target.value);
        }
      }
    );
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  first_name : <input type="text" name="first_name" value=""> <br>
  mid_name : <input type="text" name="mid_name" value=""> <br>
  last_name : <input type="text" name="last_name" value=""> <br>
  password : <input type="password" name="password" value=""> <br>
</form>
```

Demo on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egk78msu/)

I can just get the `fist name` value; for the other inputs I am not getting anything. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns ONE node - the first that matches the given selector.

Comment: @sdgluck so do we have something which can work in entire block like giving form ID or name

Comment: @user889030 I don’t understand what you mean by your comment. But selecting multiple elements is done with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). May I also suggest [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple events? Something like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1uf5b6hg/); this is just a single line of code inside the `$(document).ready(function(){` … `});`.

Comment: The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. You need to use another selector to get each element.

Comment: @dalelandry The _selector_ (which is the string) is fine. They need a different _method_, or a different approach.

Comment: @user4642212  thanks i will try that too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve what you expect you have to change two parts in your code.

The first thing to change is to use the `querySelectorAll` instead of the `querySelector`. The difference is that the `querySelector` selects only one element at a time, while the `querySelectorAll` selects all the elements matching the selectors.

The second thing you have to change is to apply the addEventListener to any element in the array as they are different components and have different events to listen to.

Here is the running code: https://jsfiddle.net/9jo1snuq/1/

I hope this helps :)

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    const user_input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]');

    user_input.forEach(
        function(userInput) {
            userInput.addEventListener(
                'blur', 
                function ( event ) {
                    var target = event.target;

                    if( target.name == "first_name" ) {
                        console.log( 'first name : ' + target.value );
                    }

                    if ( target.name == "mid_name" ) {
                        console.log( 'mid name : ' + target.value );
                    }

                    if ( target.name == "last_name" ) {
                        console.log( 'last name : ' + target.value );
                    }

                    if ( target.name == "password" ) {
                        console.log( 'password : ' + target.value );
                    }

                }
            );  
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Added better explanation to it, code works, but needs some explanation :P

Comment: thanks :) so we have to loop as mentioned by @sdgluck  querySelector return first node only

Comment: I just finished my explanation and I did code formatting ;) As you see the description is quite long and that's why I late to finish :)

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the issue you are facing with `querySelector()` vs `querySelectorAll()` addressed by other answers, I suggest you use the native [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to get all your data from the form, here is a snippet:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

```js
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
  let formData = new FormData(myForm);
  for (let input of formData) {
    console.log(input);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>


    <form id="myForm">
      first_name : <input type="text" name="first_name" value=""> <br>
      mid_name  :  <input type="text" name="mid_name" value=""> <br>
      last_name  :  <input type="text" name="last_name" value=""> <br>
      password :  <input type="password" name="mid_name" value=""> <br>
      <button id="mybutton">
       get data
      </button>
    </form>


<script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user889030, sure it is :)  its cleaner and use less code, also native javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```js
function updateResult() {
  $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('#inputs').serializeArray().map(x=>x.name + ': '+x.value)))
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('change', function() {
    updateResult()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="inputs">
  first_name : <input type="text" name="first_name" value=""> <br>
  mid_name  :  <input type="text" name="mid_name" value=""> <br>
  last_name  :  <input type="text" name="last_name" value=""> <br>
  password :  <input type="password" name="password" value=""> <br>
</form>
<div id="result">

</div>
```